# MQTT (Mosquitto) Connection pool?

Tags: java, connection-pooling, mqtt, pool, mosquitto

What would you suggest for Mosquitto connection pooling in Java? We are wasting (blocking) too much time on establishing each connection, so we think some kind of reuse would be better.

Comment: Please add some more detail about what you are doing as it will help to direct a response. I assume you have multiple threads publishing?

Comment: Sorry @hardillb, yes we've got several threads publishing, a couple thousands per minute actually, so it seems that establishing / closing a connection won't be working on a long term base, as OS (Linux Debian) doesn't seem to be freeing the TCP ports as fast as needed, and the open/close overhead is also blocking our process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the generic object pooling in the Apache commons tools https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/

But also you could extend Thread to instantiate a MQTT connection object on creation and have a persistent connection per thread. This could be combined with the built in thread pool in the standard class libraries.

I assume you do have a fixed number of threads (or a suitably constrained thread pool as burning though threads will kill performance as well)

Comment: We'll try that solution, Thanks!

Comment: Is there a working implementation of pooling now? Also how does pool handle unique client identifiers?